# SwashBuggler.swaggerDocument fails to created document

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-2.1, swashbuckle

*Project Structure:*

1. Console application - Launch the WebAPI startup
2. API Project(DLL) - Only configuration (Container and authorization and Controller class initialization using(AssemblyPart))
3. ControllerClass(DLL) - Has API methods

*SwaggerDocumentaion Configuration,
ConfigureService Class Code:*

```
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info
            {
                Title = "TestAPI",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "TestApplication API for modular monolith .NET application.",
            });

            var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            var commentsFileName = "Test.Modules.UserAccess.Facade.XML";//Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".XML";
            var commentsFile = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, commentsFileName);
            options.IncludeXmlComments(commentsFile);

            var securityToken = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
            {
                {"Bearer", new string[] { }},
            };

            options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme
            {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = "header",
                Type = "apiKey"
            });
            options.AddSecurityRequirement(securityToken);
        });
```

*Configure Class:*

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider 
  serviceProvider)
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TestAPI");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;

        });
    }
```

I have generated the XML file and copied to the output directory.

Question:

I am getting the error "Failed to Load API Definition". Help me out sort out this issue.

Comment: Found the issue.
Swashbuckle fails throws NotSupportedException exception.
To fix the exception.
Differentiate the get method correctly. e.g. [HTTPGet("{id}")] . After that document got generated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check Controller methods? 
For example, Swagger requires explicit `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet]`
If you have `Get(int id)` or `Post(..)`, this will return Failed to Load API Definition